Microsoft HyperV Domain change
I have two Hyper-V hosts with a SAN storage array. The Vol1 cluster is using less than half of the SAN. I need to rename my domain and both hypers are in the domain. This link has great information cluster migration but does not indicate if I can add the Hyper-V hosts to a second cluster simultaneously.
I could move all nodes to one host and move one Hyper-V at a time. Just not sure about best practice here. Yes, everything is backed up.
